# http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs - how can i go three months back when I click previous button

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When I press the prev button of arshaw full calendar , my requirement is to go back to the last third month e.g If current month is december then I would like to go back to September when previous button of fullcalendar clicked.

Likewise when next button is pressed i would like to show next third month which is march.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the inbuilt next/prev buttons. You can choose not to you those buttons and add your own to accomplish this though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace the button `$(".fc-button-prev")` with your own (after calendar is built), and then respond to click with:

```
yourcal.fullCalendar('gotoDate', back3);
```

(look at [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) addMonths).

Comment: gotoDate takes a year with optional month and day parameters, i.e. `yourcal.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year [, month, [ date ]] )`. See [gotoDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

Comment: See doc: "This method can also be called with a single argument, a Date object (only works in versions >= 1.3.2)."... so, you can also use Xdate.toDate() or a vanilla Date().

Comment: So it can, don't know how I missed that!